# Cannot go through the "Authentication Required" log in popup to my H2 console

Tags: java, spring-security, forms-authentication

I am using an H2 in-memory database with a few user data stored in it when I disabled to security.

However, when I enable back the security I have this authentication popup and I do not have the correct username and password to get through it.

I notice every time when I type into the authentication popup and click "OK", a SQL message will show:
*Hibernate: select userinfo0_.user_id as user_id1_1_, userinfo0_.password as password2_1_, userinfo0_.user_name as user_nam3_1_ from user_info userinfo0_ where userinfo0_.user_name=?*
the table and column info matches my H2's table setup. I think this should indicate it's looking from my database.

However, even though I type in the correct username and password, it won't let me in.

Below is my configuration class

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userInfoService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // @formatter:off
        http
                .requestMatchers().antMatchers("/login", "/logout", "/oauth/authorize", "/oauth/confirm_access")
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/h2","/h2_console/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll();
        http.csrf().disable();
        http.headers().frameOptions().disable();
        // @formatter:on
    }

    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("user").password("user").roles("USER")
                .and()
                .withUser("admin").password("admin").roles("ADMIN");
    }


    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

        auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider(){
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(this.userInfoService);
        authenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return authenticationProvider;
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

I have multiple users stored in the database, some with password of clear text, while the other with encrypted password by the Encoder above.

My only suspicion is the users from the database do not have the admin role to access the /h2 path(H2 console).

In any way, how should I get through this popup to access my h2 console?

Answer (score 0):

it has been some time since I worked with h2. I am pretty sure that you do not have to use your credentials in your database. You will instead have to setup the credentials in your application.properties file.

```
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.h2.console.path=/h2
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:yourdb;MODE=Oracle
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
```

Try to login with username `sa`and blank password.

Comment: I have the same setup in my application.properties file except for the data source url I use the test db(default). Therefore, username "sa" with a blank password does not work for me, actually.

Comment: Actually when I look at your question. You never really reach the h2 console gui, you get prompted by the spring security for credentials. The credentials are the regular credentials that you inserted into the database, whereas the h2 console will require the credentials from the property file. I would suggest you to try to remove the Spring security or enable permitAll on the h2 urls. Check to see if you can log into the h2 console without the spring security.

Answer (score 0):

it can be possible that csrf().disble() needs to be one of the first method called at http. ... when i added it at start i didn't need to authentificate anymore maybe one day my current file might help someone:

```
http.cors().and().httpBasic()
            .and().csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/nonRegistered/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/person/**").hasAuthority("USER")
            .antMatchers("/doctor/**").hasAuthority("DOCTOR")
            .antMatchers("/accommodation/**").hasAuthority("ACCOMMODATION")
            .antMatchers("/borderPatrol/**").hasAuthority("BORDERPATROL")
            .antMatchers("/console/**").permitAll() // h2 console link
            .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasAuthority("ADMIN")
            .anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated()

    ;
    http.headers().frameOptions().disable();// needed to h2 console to work
```

happy conding ;)